# Any Custom CSS to remove a grey overlay on images in Slick Slider carousel?

Tags: css, wordpress, slick.js

I am editing images on a header carousel in WP that is using slick slider. When I upload the image the text overlay that I have put on the image (bright white font in PS) becomes a dull grey colour once uploaded. The resolution isn't an issue, so I believe there is an overlay on the images which I am struggling to remove. I have tried some custom CSS to no avail, can anyone offer any solutions?

Comment: Could you give us a at least an url where we could check your problem ? or an image ?

Comment: First, I would recommand to publish your problem to wordpress stackoverflow as  well: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com
Can you describe were to add this overlay you try to add, to try to reproduce it with browser tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are having an overlay set in class `.banner .banner-images .banner-images-image:before`.
Set as followed:

```
.banner .banner-images .banner-images-image:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

So I guess you need to modify the background property as there is an opacity of 0.15.
Try to set in the above class:
`background: none;` or `background: rgba(0,0,0,0);` or `opacity: 0;` instead. Such as:

```
.banner .banner-images .banner-images-image:before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

Comment: YES!! Thank you, background: none; and Background: rgba(0,0,0,0) did nothing but replacing it for opacity: 0; has done it!!! Thank you so much I am so grateful for your help!

Comment: @ChatNoir You are welcome, then Accpet answer to show that question is solved